# footcite - print full citation using apa style

Tags: beamer, biblatex, apa-style, footcite

I use `biblatex` package and its `\footcite{}` command in my `beamer` presentation. I would like to print full reference in footnote, however using apa-like style.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% only for this example, otherwise in .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{dirac,
    title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn={9780198520115},
    series={International series of monographs on physics},
    year={1981},
    publisher={Clarendon Press},
    keywords = {physics}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,citetracker,pagetracker=page,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\let\footcite\footfullcite
\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
    Text text text \footcite{dirac}\\
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
     \printbibliography
 \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

And output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

To print full citation I need to apply `style=verbose`. Is there an easy way how to print full reference in footnote using apa-like style?

Comment: A personal note, do you really think such citations bring information to the audience ? I never felt the need for such citations in presentations. What is your point of view on this ?

Comment: This is presentation related to my thesis and it is necessary to show what was written by other authors and what was written by me.

Comment: That I can understand, and for instance it may be important to recall cited papers at the end if people want to have a look at it afterwards, or for the questions. However, do you think people need to know that Dirac had 3 first names, or that the journal number was 27 or the editor ^^. Don't you think that **in the slide / during the presentation**, a lighter information would have a greater readability/space ratio e.g. "Dirac, *The principles of quantum mechanics*, 1981"

Comment: Well, I would like to show name (even with 3 first names as there are some authors with the same surname), year, name of article/book and journal and I do prefer apa-like cite: Dirac, P. A. M. (1981). The principles of quantum mechanics. I assumed that there may be "already-existing" solution to my problem which is for example easy to apply via package options. And of course, as stated in example, I print bibliography at the end of the presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you could combine `verbose` and `apa` as follows

```
citestyle=verbose, bibstyle=apa,
```

even though I would in generally not recommend that.

But since you are only using `\footcite` and say `\let\footcite\footfullcite` anyway, just

```
style=apa,
```

will produce the same result in your MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage[style=apa, citetracker, pagetracker=page, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\let\footcite\footfullcite
\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
    Text text text \footcite{sigfridsson}
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}
     \printbibliography
 \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image: APA style citation]